# Anything above 2 rpm it loses power

Tags: power-loss

My headlights flicker or either go dim and the battery gauge is decreasing  strength as i accelerate. Please tell me which is the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From your very brief description and minimal information, I'd suggest your alternator has gone out and the vehicle is running on battery power. You could try recharging the battery and see if the car will run better. You'd want to check the battery voltage with a multimeter while the vehicle is running (after battery is charged). Should be around 13.5-14.1vdc. If it's around 12vdc and is dropping continually, the alternator is bad.

Comment: I'd guess the belt to the alternator is slipping. Have a mechanic check it.